# Can't remove folder on macOS - Directory not empty

Tags: macos, delete-file, macos-catalina

I have strange problem with removing empty folder on macOS Catalina.

Right now I have ended up with new ideas how to remove that thing.

```
felixd@Felix-MacPro:~/a$ ls -of delme/
total 0
drwx------  3 felixd   96  4 cze  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 felixd  160  8 maj 20:55 ..

felixd@Felix-MacPro:~/a$ ls -laf delme/
total 0
drwx------  3 felixd  staff   96  4 cze  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 felixd  staff  160  8 maj 20:55 ..
felixd@Felix-MacPro:~/a$ rm -rf delme/

rm: delme/: Directory not empty
```

This folder is not being used by any application. 
I have already tried to remove it while starting macOS in rescue mode.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: do you have proper permissions for `delme`?  I notice the `.` entry has different permissions than `..`.

Comment: It's not a permission problem. I can easily move this folder around, change permissions, name etc... but I can't remove it ;) 

Finder tells me that folder is in use
In console it tells me that folder is not empty.